# Displaying xml data in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a XML that holds data and I currently have a j query function that gets that data and displays it in a table.

movie.xml

```
<Dataset>
    <Record>
        <Movie_Title>Breath</Movie_Title>
        <Genre>Horror</Genre>
        <Cinema_number>1</Cinema_number>
        <price>8.50</price>
        <Director>Simon Baker</Director>
        <Sessions>
           <Date>
             Monday
             <Time>9:30</Time>
             <Time>11:30</Time>
             <Time>13:30</Time>
             <Time>15:30</Time>
             <Time>17:30</Time>
            </Date>

           <Date>
             Tuesday
             <Time>9:30</Time>
             <Time>11:30</Time>
             <Time>13:30</Time>
             <Time>15:30</Time>
             <Time>17:30</Time>
           </Date>
        </Sessions>
    </Record>
</Dataset>
```

This is what I am using to display the data in a table at the moment

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
    xhttp.send();
    return xhttp.responseXML;
} 

  function searchXML()
  {
var xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("/movie.xml");
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Movie_Title");
var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
var size = input.length;
if (input == "" || input == null)
  {
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "please enter a movie Title!";
    return false;
  } else 
  {

   var divText ="";  
   for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
        {
         // Check if movie title is same as value entered in input text
          if (x.length > 0 && xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Movie_Title")  [i].childNodes[0].nodeValue == document.getElementById("input").value) 
          {
        var Movie_Title = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Movie_Title") [i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var Genre = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Genre")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var date = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Date")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var time = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Time")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var cinema_number = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Cinema_number")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var price = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("price")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var director = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Director")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

        //appending value of each iterations
        divText += "<h1> The session times are: </h1><br /><table border = 1> <tr><th>Movie Title</th><th>Date</th><th>Time</th><th>Cinema number</th><th>Price</th>"
        + "<tr><td>" + Movie_Title + "</td><td>" + date + "</td><td>" + time + "</td><td>" + cinema_number + "</td><td>" + price + "</td></tr>" + "</table>"; 



      } 


    }

      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = divText;

    }

  }
```

This is my html table

```
<div class = search_section>
Movie Title <input type="text" name="Movie_Title" id="input">
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick=searchXML()>
<br />
<br />
<div id="results"></div>
</div>
```

The problem I have at the moment is that when the table is populated it is only displaying one row and nothing else. For example:

**Movie Title**:Breath
**Date:** Monday
**Time:** 9:30
**Cinema Number:** 1
**Price:** 8.50

What i really want is for the table to populated with many rows for each date within the  sessions tag and each time within Date tags in the xml file.

For example:

**Movie Title**:Breath
**Date:** Monday
**Time:** 11:30
**Cinema Number:** 1
**Price:** 8.50

**Movie Title**:Breath
**Date:** Monday
**Time:** 13:30
**Cinema Number:** 1
**Price:** 8.50

... rest of the time for monday

**Movie Title**:Breath
**Date:** Tuesday
**Time:** 9:30
**Cinema Number:** 1
**Price:** 8.50

**Movie Title**:Breath
**Date:** Tuesday
**Time:** 11:30
**Cinema Number:** 1
**Price:** 8.50

... rest of the times for Tuesday

Any help or idea you can give me?

Comment: Extracting data would be a pain for `<Date>`

Comment: `var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Movie_Title");` selects one item from the xml. You'll need to loop through the sessions, date and then time as well to build the table.

Comment: Any help on how I would go about doing that?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is a working solution**

You need more than one loop. You need loop for every movie, every day and every hour.

```js
function searchXML() {

  var parser, xmlDoc;
  var text = "<Dataset>" + "<Record>" + "<Movie_Title>Breath</Movie_Title>" + "<Genre>Horror</Genre>" + "<Cinema_number>1</Cinema_number>" + "<price>8.50</price>" + "<Director>Simon Baker</Director>" + "<Sessions>" + "<Date>" + "Monday" + "<Time>9:30</Time>" + "<Time>11:30</Time>" + "<Time>13:30</Time>" + "<Time>15:30</Time>" + "<Time>17:30</Time>" + "</Date>" + "<Date>" + "Tuesday" + "<Time>9:30</Time>" + "<Time>11:30</Time>" + "<Time>13:30</Time>" + "<Time>15:30</Time>" + "<Time>17:30</Time>" + "</Date>" + "</Sessions>" + "</Record>" + "<Record>" + "<Movie_Title>Test</Movie_Title>" + "<Genre>Comedy</Genre>" + "<Cinema_number>2</Cinema_number>" + "<price>9.50</price>" + "<Director>Test Baker</Director>" + "<Sessions>" + "<Date>" + "Monday" + "<Time>9:30</Time>" + "<Time>11:30</Time>" + "<Time>15:30</Time>" + "<Time>17:30</Time>" + "</Date>" + "<Date>" + "Wednesday" + "<Time>11:30</Time>" + "<Time>13:30</Time>" + "<Time>15:30</Time>" + "</Date>" + "</Sessions>" + "</Record>" + "</Dataset>";

  parser = new DOMParser();
  xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/xml");
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Movie_Title");
  var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var size = input.length;
  if (input == "" || input == null) {
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "please enter a movie Title!";
    return false;
  } else {
    var divText = "<h1> The session times are: </h1><br /><table border = 1> <tr><th>Movie Title</th><th>Date</th><th>Time</th><th>Cinema number</th><th>Price</th>";
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      var record = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Record")[i];
      var movie_Title = record.getElementsByTagName("Movie_Title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      if (x.length > 0 && movie_Title == document.getElementById("input").value) {
        var genre         = record.getElementsByTagName("Genre")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var cinema_number = record.getElementsByTagName("Cinema_number")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var price         = record.getElementsByTagName("price")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var director      = record.getElementsByTagName("Director")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

        for (var dateNum = 0; dateNum < record.getElementsByTagName("Date").length; dateNum++) {
          var date = record.getElementsByTagName("Date")[dateNum].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
          for (var num = 0; num < record.getElementsByTagName("Date")[dateNum].getElementsByTagName("Time").length; num++) {
            var time = record.getElementsByTagName("Time")[num].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

            divText += "<tr><td>" + movie_Title + "</td><td>" + date + "</td><td>" + time + "</td><td>" + cinema_number + "</td><td>" + price + "</td></tr>";
          }
        }
      }
    }
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = divText + "</table>";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class=s earch_section>
  Movie Title
  <br /> (Try: Breath or Test)
  <br />
  <input type="text" name="Movie_Title" id="input" value="Breath">
  <br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="searchXML()">
  <br />
  <br />
  <div id="results"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping it works great, Just a follow up question: I have the string stored in the variable text in an external xml file at the moment. Any help with how i could use reference and use that file instead of the string stored in var text?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, its just that i dont know where to load/reference the file with your solution.

Comment: Oh no worries i got it working,Thanksyou so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You are only adding the elements that meet this condition:

```
if (x.length > 0 && if (x.length > 0 && xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Movie_Title") [i].childNodes[0].nodeValue == document.getElementById("input").value)
```

which is only the one that you have set in your input